# Connect and send two shells together

Tags: c

After seeing the following tutorial (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-demonstrate-fork-and-pipe/), I realize that I can't get two terminals to communicate with each other, and I can't find any resource on the web that talks about it. To be more precise, I'm trying to make two terminals communicate together with the same code but not with the same arguments.
Here are the two functions I use:

```
int connect_parent(void)
{
    write(1, "my_pid: ", 9);
    my_putnbr(getpid());
    write(1, "\nwaiting for enemy connection...\n", 34);
    pause();
    signal(SIGINT, handle_sigint);
}

int connect_child(char * char_pid)
{
    int parent_pid = my_getnbr(char_pid);
    int my_pid = getpid();
    int fd[2];

    if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
        write(2, "Pipe failed\n", 13);
        return 84;
    }
    close(fd[0]);
    write(fd[1], "test", 5);
    close(fd[1]);
    if (kill(parent_pid, SIGINT) != -1) {
        write(1, "my_pid: ", 9);
        my_putnbr(my_pid);
        write(1, "\nsuccessfully connected\n", 25);
        pause();
        return 0;
    }
    write(2, "Wrong pid\n", 11);
    return 84;
}
```

Here is my main function:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    if (argc == 2) {
        if (my_strstr(argv[1], "-h") != 0)
            help_flag();
        if (error_handling(argv[1]) != 84) {
            connect_parent();
            return 0;
        } else
            return 84;
    } else if (argc == 3) {
        if (error_handling(argv[2]) != 84) {
            connect_child(argv[1]);
            return 0;
        } else
            return 84;
    }
    return 84;
}
```

The parent function for the first terminal, and the child function for the second.
The goal is to send a simple text when both terminals are connected together.

At the moment my first terminal is waiting for a signal with the `pause()` function and when the second one sends a SIGINT signal, the first exit.

Here is the command I run on my first terminal:

```
./navy ./pos1
```

And here is the command I execute on the second one:

```
./navy <pid of the first terminal> ./pos2
```

Do you have a resource I can rely on or an explanation of how to do this?

Comment: What is `./navy`?

Comment: @Barmar ./navy is the name of my executable

Comment: Yes, so show the code for `navy`. What does the `main` look like? What other code is missing?

Comment: You haven't shown the `main()` function, what does it do with the arguments? How is it connecting the two processes together?

Comment: `pipe()` is only useful for connecting a parent with its own child process. You can't use it to connect unrelated processes.

Comment: You could use a named pipe for this.

Comment: Maybe you can create shared memory that both programs can access (see `ftok()`, `shmget` and `shm` variants) and there store `connect_parent`'s PID so you can send a signal through `connect_child`. But if you already pass the PID as an argument, why don't you just send a signal to the other process using `kill`?

Comment: I just modified with my main function

Comment: What does `handle_sigint` do? You need to call `signal()` *before* calling `pause()`. Otherwise, the SIGINT will just terminate the parent.

Comment: handle_sigint is a function that I have deleted (an example function that just print something)

Comment: @user157629 Yes but if I send a signal using kill(), I cant pass whatever I want, like strings or integer

Comment: Then you just need to store the text in a shared memory variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both programs will need to execute this lines:

```
key_t key = ftok(<existing_file>, <random_number>); //for example: ftok("navy.c", 12);

char **text;

int memid = shmget(key, sizeof(char *), IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0600);  //if this returns -1, an error occured

*text = shmat(memid, 0, 0); //You attach the pointer to the shared memory variable position
```

Then you can modify `text` as you want to. Both programs will "see" this variable.

Don't forget to `shmdt(*text)` (detach the pointer) in both executions and clear that memory space you created for your shared variable executing: `shmctl(memid, IPC_RMID, NULL);` in just one of the process after you don't need the shared variable anymore.

Comment: `ftok()` will return will be a free memory address in your system and store it in the `key_t` variable

Comment: You've forgotten the C in IPC_EXCL I think